# ffmpeg and php upload

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have never used ffmpeg and was wondering if this script looked right and would work.

I would like to convert the uploaded video to .flv and then add the filename to the hidden input

```
<input type='hidden' id='ajax_image_url' value='".$txt.".flv'>
```

But would also like to delete the original file after.

Any help/comments would be greatly appreciated.

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $name = $_FILES['thisimage']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['thisimage']['size'];

    if(strlen($name))
    {
        list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);

        if(in_array($ext, $valid_formats_img))
        {
            if($size<($image_size_limit*$image_size_limit))
            {
                $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                $tmp = $_FILES['thisimage']['tmp_name'];

                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                {
                    echo "<img src='media/".$actual_image_name."'  class='showthumb' /><input type='hidden' id='video' value='0' /><input type='hidden' id='ajax_image_url' value='".$actual_image_name."' />";
                }
                else
                    echo '<b style="color:#fff;">'.$txt_img_err1.'</b>';
            }
            else
                echo '<b style="color:#fff;">'.$txt_img_up_size.'</b>'; 
        }
        else if(in_array($ext, $valid_formats_vid))
        {
            if($size<($videos_size_limit*$videos_size_limit))
            {
                $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                $tmp = $_FILES['thisimage']['tmp_name'];

                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                {

                exec('ffmpeg -i '$path.$actual_image_name.' '$path.$txt.'.flv');    

                ?>

                   <!-- START OF THE PLAYER EMBEDDING TO COPY-PASTE --> 
                    <object id="player" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" name="player" width="328" height="200"> 
                    <param name="movie" value="player.swf" /> 
                    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /> 
                    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /> 
                    <param name="flashvars" value="file=media/<?php echo $txt?>.flv" /> 
                    <embed 
                        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                        id="player2"
                        name="player2"
                        src="player.swf" 
                        width="328" 
                        height="200"
                        allowscriptaccess="always" 
                        allowfullscreen="true"
                        flashvars="file=media/<?php echo $txt?>.flv" 
                    /> 
                </object> 
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
                <!-- END OF THE PLAYER EMBEDDING --> 
                <?php
                echo "<input type='hidden' id='ajax_image_url' value='".$txt.".flv' /><input type='hidden' id='video' value='1' />";
                }
                else
                    echo '<b style="color:#fff;">'.$txt_img_err1.'</b>';
            }
            else
                echo '<b style="color:#fff;">'.$txt_img_up_size.'</b>'; 
        }
        else
            echo '<b style="color:#fff;">'.$txt_img_err2.'</b>';    
    }
    else
        echo '<b style="color:#fff;">'.$txt_img_err3.'</b>';

    exit;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you run it and find out if it "would work"? (Then come back to discuss problems or improvements)

Comment: I have tried it. it works fine uploading the original video but does not convert to the .flv so the ffmpeg line is doing nothing

Comment: Try the ffmpeg command manually (outside of your script) to see if ffmpeg is the issue or not.

Comment: Or pass an array as a second parameter to `exec()`, it will be filled with `ffmpeg`'s output, including possible errors. See http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: tried manual ffmpeg and worked fine. i then added , $output to end of exec and var_dump($output) --- i get: array(0) { }

Comment: Check www-data (or whatever your webserver is running as) has permission to write to the current dir, you might also want to define exactly where you want the output file to go, otherwise it'll default to where the script is being ran from.